# Laravel validation - validate a specific field of a relation

Tags: laravel

I have created a request class for an update API request. In the rules method I have the fields to validate. For one field I have to do a more complex validation.

**Example**

**ModelA** should be updated. But only if the owner (**User**) of the ModelA is `null` in a field x (`special_field_x`).

```
ModelA belongsTo User
User hasMany ModelA

ModelA [id (int), title (string), owner (int)]
User [id (int), name (string), special_field_x (string, nullable)]
```

**My approach & question**

I found an interesting rule function in the Laravel documentaion which I tried. It works but I wonder if this is the right function and if there is another way?

```php
// ModelARequest.php
    public function rules(PermissionRepository $permissionRepository)
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'owner' => ['required', 'exists:users,id',
 Rule::prohibitedIf($modelA->responsible->isUserEnable())], // isUserEnable returns a boolean

// ModelA responsible Method
   public function responsible(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
'exists:users,id,special_field_x,NULL'
```

This means that `special_field_x` must be `NULL`. You can add more condition using (,) column name and value.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) It is very helpful. One question: Is that the same like:             `'responsible' => ['required', Rule::exists('users', 'id')->whereNull('special_field_x')],`?

Comment: I noticed that it is correct not to have a space between the comma and ZERO. With a space the validation would always fail. Is that correct?

Comment: @MartinTTS that first one could do it too. I never put spaces between the comma.

Answer (score 0):

the answer given before is a good one in my opinion, the one you also found is a good one, however I suggest another method if it can help you

To perform more complex validation on a specific field when updating an A model using a custom query class, you can follow these steps:

Create a custom query class using the Laravel artisan command:

```
php artisan make:request UpdateModelARequest
```

Open the generated UpdateModelARequest class and modify the rules method by adding the specific validation for the special_field_x

```
$modelAId = $this->route('modelA'); // Obtenez l'ID du modèle A depuis la route

return [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'special_field_x' => [
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($modelAId) {
            $modelA = ModelA::find($modelAId);
            $owner = $modelA->owner;

            if (!is_null($owner) && $value !== $owner->special_field_x) {
                $fail('Validation error message.'); // Remplacez par le message d'erreur souhaité
            }
        },
    ],
    // Autres règles de validation pour les autres champs de ModelA
];
```

I don't pretend to say that it will solve your problem but it is a proposal