# Laravel whereNull function for multiple fields use?

Tags: laravel

How can I check multiple fields in Laravel that they are not null? I'm thinking of writing my multiple fields check with multiple whereNull methods one after the other:

```php
Rule::exists('users', 'id')
  ->whereNull('field_x')
  ->whereNull('field_y')],
```

Intuitively I would have thought that you can pass an array to the whereNull function. Unfortunately this is not possible. Are there other ways to do this?

This would work: `->whereNotNull(['field_x','field_y'])` but  i need to the check that this fields are null. Like this: `->whereNull(['field_x','field_y'])`

Comment: there is function whereNotNull in laravel

Comment: @Sumitkumar But i will pass the validation if the fields explicit null.

Comment: 'exists:users,id,special_field_x,NULL'
reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312318/laravel-validation-validate-a-specific-field-of-a-relation

Answer (score 1):

You can loop though your columns to check with `whereNull` method like below,

```
$columns = ['field_x','field_y'];

$rules = Rule::exists('users', 'id');

foreach($columns as $column){
    $rules->whereNull($column);
}
$rulesFinal = $rules;
```

Comment: Thx! You are right it is also possible. In conclusion i see, that the solution with multiple whereNull() function is the shortest way. right? : `Rule::exists('users', 'id')
  ->whereNull('field_x')
  ->whereNull('field_y')],`

Comment: @MartinTTS Yup! you may loop through like this when there are bunch of columns. instead of repeatedly writing same thing.